# How to make a 2D object bounce back and forth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMovement1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private bool moveLeft = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool moveRight = false;
    Vector2 movement;


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Move());

        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = .25f;
    }
 
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (moveLeft == true)
        {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position - movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            Debug.Log("Move left is true");
        }
        if (moveRight == true)
        {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            Debug.Log("Move Right is true");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Move()
    {
        if (moveLeft)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

            moveLeft = false;
            moveRight = true;
        } 
        if (moveRight)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

            moveRight = false;
            moveLeft = true;
        }

    }
}
```

I am not really sure why this doesn't work as it should just cause the bools to switch after 0.25 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your switching continously, not just once.

```
IEnumerator Move() 
{
    while(true) // do this forever
    {
        if (moveLeft)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

            moveLeft = false;
            moveRight = true;
        } 
        else if (moveRight) 
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

            moveRight = false;
            moveLeft = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This can actually be simplified to

```
IEnumerator Move() 
{
    while(true) // do this forever
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        moveLeft = !moveLeft;
    }
}
```

Move right is encoded into move left, there is only one bit of information here :)

```
bool MoveRight => !moveLeft
```

Comment: Also check out [Mathf.PingPong](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html)